# Don't start Pi on power connection

Tags: boot, power, power-supply

I've currently got my raspberry pi setup with a power switch that wakes it up from power off (using GPIO3) and shuts it down safely using a simple python script. Pretty basic stuff.

The problem arises when I temporarily loose power, or unplug the Raspberry Pi to move it. Reconnecting it also boots the Raspberry Pi again. What I want, is to only have the pi turned on when I press the power button.

Is there any way to disable the auto power up on connection of power?

For context, I'm using a Pi Zero W, with a 5v power supply connected directly to the 5v rail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply no.

The only way to prevent boot is to pull the reset pin (labelled RUN) low.